# How to get Authorization Code from Azure App using HTTP Request in C#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created a .Net Application and to access certain outlook graph API's i need to fetch the access token and to get this access token i want authorization code which need to be passed. 
As far as the article for **Authorization Code Flow**, I have seen examples where we can get the authorization code by using the browser, whereas, in my case i want to retrieve the auth code within the application.
Is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: Hi @DCZ. Which Graph APIs are you referring to? Many of them support an app-only token when you don't have or need an end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get Authorization Code from Azure App using HTTP Request in C#?

In short, **it's impossible**.

The part of OAuth 2.0 authorization flow is as below:

[image]

When getting authorization code, user need to enter credential and consent permission which is **an Interactive request**. So, it's impossible to use C# code getting the code directly.