# Microsoft Graph OnlineMeeting API returning Status: NotFound (404) error

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create online meeting using below code and passing all the details of app registration.
Still its returning 404 error.

```
static string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    
IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(LaiAppClientID).WithClientSecret(Secret).WithRedirectUri(redirectURI).Build();
    
AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(app, scopesssss);
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
    
graphClient = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta",
                         new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                              async (requestMessage) =>
                              {
                                  var token = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopesssss).WithAuthority(String.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", tenantID), true).ExecuteAsync();
                                  requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token.AccessToken);
                               
                              }));
    
var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
                {
                    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-07-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
                    EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-07-12T22:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
                    Subject = "My First MS Teams Meeting",
                    AudioConferencing= audioConferencing
    
                };
    
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    return await graphClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
                    
                });
var d = task.Result;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your code shows, you use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to get access token, then create onlineMeeting by MS Graph API. Please see my code, it works well.

```
string clientId = "<your-client-id>";
string clientSecret = "<your-client-secret>";
string redirectUri = "<your-redirect-url>";
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>";
string authorizationCode = "<the authorization code>";

string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .WithAuthority(authority)
    .Build();

AuthorizationCodeProvider auth = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(app, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) => {

    // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
    var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, authorizationCode).ExecuteAsync();

    // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
    
})
);

var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
{
    StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-07-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
    EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-07-12T22:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
    Subject = "My First MS Teams Meeting"
};

await graphServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
```

**Note:**

*authorizationCode*: The auth code flow need to get this code first, then you could obtain the access token for API. See this [step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code), you could request the url by browser and sign in with user, then it will response the code.

*permission*: To let it work, you need to add the permission(your application -> API permissions -> MS Graph -> **Delegated permissions** -> OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite) to create onlineMeeting, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions).
[image]

**Reference:**

Microsoft Graph API about creating onlineMeeting by C#: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request)

The [sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth) about using `AuthorizationCodeProvider` and more [details](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-with-authorization-codes-on-web-apps) about the code.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Message: Create online meeting with application permission is only
> supported in beta.

The API(/v1.0) just supports delegated permission(OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite), not application permission. You could see this in the previous note.

[image]

Both the `/beta` also only supports delegated permission, see:

[image]

Comment: Thanx for your reply.I have both permission assigned to App.api permission as below:Now i am getting below err:
OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite--Delegated--Read and create user's online meetings-Granted 
OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All--Application-Read and create online meetings
Code: NotImplemented
Message: Create online meeting with application permission is only supported in beta.

Comment: @sdsUser Have you tried the code in my answer? What is the version of package `Microsoft.Graph`? I used the latest one(3.12.0).

Comment: The end point [`/v1.0`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [`/beta`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-beta) can also be used to create onlineMeeting, but just `/beta` support **Update onlineMeeting**. If you call the 1.0 API to update onlineMeeting, the error will occur.

Comment: Yes I tried ur code.I am using Microsoft.Graph version 3.12 using graphServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting); .Still getting err;Message: Create online meeting with application permission is only supported in beta. Using scope { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };gives above err . and using scope { "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/.default" } gives err MsalServiceException: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://graph.microsoft.com/beta was not found in the tenant named ....

Comment: Hi, @sdsUser. I'm sorry. I missed the "application permission" in your error. The API just supports delegated permission, but not application permission. I add it as **UPDATE** in my reply.

Comment: Hi @Pamela Peng u want me to remove application read.Write permission and only keep delegated read write permission.

Comment: Yes. As the screenshot in my answer shows, I added only the delegated permission.

Comment: Hi @Pamela,thanx a lot for replies.I hv removed application permission.plz tell me scope to define?if i use 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/.default",https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/.default then getting err "MsalServiceException: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0 was not found in the tenant named ".also when scope .="https://graph.microsoft.com/OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite" err is "MsalServiceException: AADSTS70011: 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite is not valid."

Comment: First, both `"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/.default"` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/.default` do not exist. Learn about scope and permission by this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent). To understand easily, learn the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) first. 
.

Comment: `https://graph.microsoft.com/OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite` can be used, I'm not sure what's wrong with you, maybe you use [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), the scope of this flow need to be affixed with the .default suffix. But delegate permission doesn't support client credentials flow.

Comment: Hi, @sdsUser. Have you use this method `app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, authorizationCode)` to get access token? I tried with scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite`, they all worked well. see https://i.stack.imgur.com/0faae.png

Comment: yes but i am not able to get authorizationCode programatically bcoz it comes browser and asks for signin so response i am unable to read.if u have any code to get authorizationCode will be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Pamela,I tried using app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, authorizationCode) to get access token.and scope https://graph.microsoft.com/OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite suggested by you.I am able to create a meeting successfully.But concern is i am unable to get AuthorizationCode pro-grammatically so i take it manually from browser.so plz proved code to get  AuthorizationCode pro-grammatically.Thanx a lot.

Comment: @sdsUser It seems impossible to get AuthorizationCode pro-grammatically. You need a web view to signing in with user, but not just request the url and get code. See the two similar issues: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61002040/13308381 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59870871/13308381. Could you please raise a new thread for the new question?