# MsalServiceException: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0 not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Scope value = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" OR "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta"

gives below err in asp.net c#.

> MsalServiceException: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named
> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0 was not found in the tenant named
> 'xxxxxxxx'. This can happen if the application has not been installed
> by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the
> tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong
> tenant.

code:

```
string clientId = AppClientID;
        string clientSecret = Secret;
        string redirectUri =`enter code here` System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["redirectUri"]; 
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantID;              
        string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };        
        //string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/.default" };        
        IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(authority)
            .Build();
        AuthorizationCodeProvider auth = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(app, scopes);
        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
        {           
            var authResult = app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).WithAuthority(authority, true).ExecuteAsync().Result.AccessToken.ToString();
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult);
        }));      
        var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
        {
            StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-07-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
            EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-07-12T22:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
            Subject = "My First MS Teams Meeting"
        };
        await graphServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
```

Comment: Please change the `scope` to: `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

Comment: using scope =  https://graph.microsoft.com/.default  .posted code in question.plz check.

Comment: Still get the same error? I didn't see `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0` is put anywhere in your code.

Comment: I am new here so thanx for formatting @Allen.When i tried 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0' i got parameter 'scope' is not valid. The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0 is not valid.

Comment: Don't use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/.default`. Just as Carl suggested, use `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. I think the error you posted here won't occur if you set the scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

Comment: OK.I tried https://graph.microsoft.com/.default as per both of u then i am getting err 'Code: NotImplemented.Message: Create online meeting with application permission is only supported in beta.'To resolve this err when i tried scope "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/.default" again i getting err MsalServiceException: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://graph.microsoft.com/beta was not found in the tenant.so need guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If I set "**scope**" to `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/.default`, your problem can be reproduced, so please make sure to set "scope" to `https://graph .microsoft.com/.default`.

[image]

2. You cannot use the `[AcquireTokenForClient][2]` function in the **auth code flow** to obtain a token. It is generally applied to the **client credential flow**. This flow does not require user login, so even if you use this function to obtain a token, it is not correct. You can parse the To view the token, it does not have the permissions you added in the portal. For the **auth code flow**, you should use `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode` to obtain the token, as [Pamela](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700668/microsoft-graph-onlinemeeting-api-returning-status-notfound-404-error) mentioned.

Use `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode` to obtain the token and parse:

[image]
[image]

3.Code:

```
            string clientId = "{clientId}";
            string clientSecret = "{clientSecret}";
            string redirectUri = "{redirectUri}";
            string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}";
            string authorizationCode = "code";

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

            IConfidentialClientApplication app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                .WithAuthority(authority)
                .Build();

            AuthorizationCodeProvider auth = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(app, scopes);

            GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) => {

                // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
                var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, authorizationCode).ExecuteAsync();

                // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

            })
            );

            var onlineMeeting = new OnlineMeeting
            {
                StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-07-12T21:30:34.2444915+00:00"),
                EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-07-12T22:00:34.2464912+00:00"),
                Subject = "My First MS Teams Meeting"
            };

            await graphServiceClient.Me.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting);
```

Comment: Thanx for such a detail explanation @Carl.For using AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode() i dont know how to get authorizationCode shown by u below:'var authResult = await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, authorizationCode).ExecuteAsync();'.plz provide a code to get authorizationCode .

Comment: Hi @Carl,@Allen,@Pamela,,I tried using app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, authorizationCode) to get access token.and scope graph.microsoft.com/OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite suggested by you.I am able to create a meeting successfully.But concern is i am unable to get AuthorizationCode pro-grammatically so i take it manually from browser.so plz proved code to get AuthorizationCode pro-grammatically.Thanx a lot.

Comment: @sdsUser   You cannot obtain the `code` in a pro-grammatically manner, because obtaining the `code` is an interactive process. You must first log in to the user, and the `code` needs to be dynamically obtained in the browser.